# Is it possible to have different authentication provider for my Azure App service?

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization, azure-web-app-service

The Authentication/Authorization settings for my API app only provide AAD, FB, Google and Twitter. I want to use different authorization provider (different chat app such as Kakaotalk/LINE) and eventhough their API also give me token I don't know how I can make my backend authorize those tokens.

I wonder if it's possible to have custom authorization based on different OAuth token provided by different service? If not can you suggest what steps should I take to do authorization for my api app service?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to use custom identity providers if you're using .NET for your API app.  Some useful references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#custom-auth

https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/